# How can I add a where condition in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm making a table in ssrs which calculates my sick percentage.
In my query I have al column named 'billable' where I labelled all the hours of my employees as internal, billable or sick.

Now I want ssrs to calculate ='hours sick' / 'hours internal, billable and sick'. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show some code you have tried ..!! [How to ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=Sum(IIF((Fields!billable.Value="hours sick"), Fields!hours.Value,cdec(0))) / Sum(Fields!hours.Value)
```